# How can I vary protect_from_forgery based on subdomain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, subdomain, csrf-protection

So this question has two parts, but can likely be solved by being able to detect the subdomain within ApplicationController.

The solution I was planning to use is something along the lines of:

```
if request.subdomain == 'api'
    protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
else
    protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end
```

But `request` is not being resolved... I am getting this:

```
undefined local variable or method `request' for ApplicationController:Class
```

Comment: I found answers that should work here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23673040/override-the-protect-from-forgery-strategy-in-a-controller